# Projects with StructureMap and Unobtrusive don't register Subscriptions

Tags: structuremap, nservicebus, nservicebus3

Current Production NUGET build.
Windows 8 x64
VS2012

I followed the sample on how to create a pub/sub.
The default builder was swapped out for structuremap, and everything worked fine.
I delete the queues and the database for raven and the console complains about client@machine name doesn't exist.

I delete the queues and db again and comment out the structuremap stuff and restore the default builder and everything works again.

Same problem with new projects that don't use the default builder to setup the queues first.

Initial

```
        Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
```

With StructureMap

```
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            //.DefaultBuilder()
            .StructureMapBuilder(new Container(new DependencyRegistry()))
            .JsonSerializer()
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
    }

    public class DependencyRegistry : Registry
    {
        public DependencyRegistry()
        {
            Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefiningEventsAs needs to go right after the call to With(). This is a known issue we'll make sure to fix it in a future version.